# Does having more crew use up more supplies?

Tags: sunless-skies

You definitely did use more supplies in Sunless Sea, but I'm not seeing a clear correlation between number of crew and supply consumption in Sunless Skies and it's hard to test because it's hard to get rid of crew. Is it best to have as few as you can get away with or should you fill your ship up to the max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, as more weight on your ship (cargo and equipment) drains your fuel faster.

source : https://steamcommunity.com/app/596970/discussions/0/1777136225027622282/

Comment: I also noticed recently in the loading screen that is explicitly states that having more crew uses more supplies (which I take to mean not just fuel).

Comment: Maybe my answer is not clear enough, I wanted to say that more crew drains your supplies faster and the same mechanic exist for weight and equipment on fuel. I don't think that more crew on your ship drains fuel faster but I'm not sure now

Comment: I follow you now. I think I better watch to see if there is a change to fuel efficiency next time I'm recruiting crew because that might be another concern.